# Strongly typed user control model binding not working in Asp.Net MVC 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, model-binding

I am using a strongly typed user control in one of the view. The coding is as follows:

This is the call in my View:

```
<table>
    <%    
    for (int i = 0; i < ((List<string>)ViewData["MyProjects"]).Count; i++)
    {
        string viewIndex = "MyTasks" + i.ToString();%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%Html.RenderPartial("ProjectTasks", ViewData[viewIndex]); %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

My user control has the following code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<Application_Service.DTOs.TaskDTO>>" %>
<%if(Model.Count > 0){ %>
<table>   
    <tr>
        <td>Task Name</td>
        <td>Task Status</td>
    </tr>
    <% foreach (var item in ViewData.Model) {%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%:Html.Label(item.TaskName); %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%:Html.Label(item.TaskStatus.ToString());%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%} %>
</table>
<%} %>
```

The problem is that I get an error while trying to call bind the model in user control. 
I am not sure what is the problem here.

Error Message:

> "ProjectTasks.ascx(14): error CS1026:
>   ) expected". at the Html.RenderPartial
>   call.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: It says"ProjectTasks.ascx(14): error CS1026: ) expected". at the Html.RenderPartial call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. html.Label should not end with ";". 
`<%:Html.Label(item.TaskStatus.ToString());%>` should be `<%:Html.Label(item.TaskStatus.ToString())%>` Semicolon removed.

This is basically issue with the MVC.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get rid of the `;` on the end of your `<%:` statements:

```
<td> 
    <%:Html.Label(item.TaskName) %> 
</td> 
<td> 
    <%:Html.Label(item.TaskStatus.ToString())%> 
</td>
```

**Edit:** Also, since I noticed you posted seconds before me that you found it, this applies to whenever you use the `<%:` or `<%=` syntax and is not `Html.Label` specific.